# Mutter mapping not working

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mutter

Hello Ubuntu community,

I try to create a setup script for all my settings that I fire after a fresh installation to restore all of my settings.

The script includes:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left "['<Super>h']"
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right "['<Super>l']"
```

After execution the first mapping works as expected but the second one does not.
Any idea why that could be the case or how I could analyze the problem?

Thanks for any help,
Franz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a default Ubuntu install, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> is used to lock the screen. You will need to disable (or change) that keybinding first:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver ['']
```

That would be in a default Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 or Ubuntu 20.20 install. If on your system the key is mapped elsewhere, you can find its assignment with the command (with thanks to Franz):

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep "\['<Super>l'\]"
```

Comment: I thought conflicting mappings will be set to empty by default (and in fact nothing happens when I use <Super>l). However even after explicitly disabling the screen lock mapping it is not working.

Comment: I assume you at least logged out and back in before coming to a final conclusion that this does not work? Resetting the shell may also do.

Comment: I did now. After the reboot I checked the mappings with `gsettings get`. Sadly the problem remains.

Comment: So nothing happens when you press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>? What is the output of the command `gsettings get org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right`?

Comment: exactly nothing happens. The output is `['<Super>l']`.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Of course I expect that it usually works fine that is why part of my question is how to debug my setup.

Comment: Found a solution based on your answer. Ty.

Comment: Thank you as well. I incorporated your answer also in my answer (with credits to you ;) for easy reference of other users who also would happen to have the key assigned elsewhere than the default.

Answer (score 1):

Based on vanadium's answer I found that indeed my mapping was blocked by conflicting mappings. To find those I used

`gsettings list-recursively | grep "\['<Super>l'\]"`

After that I disabled all with a command like the one given by vanadium.